# .xsd, .xml, and Excel Troubles

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I'll preface by saying 2 days ago I learned of the existence of .xml and .xsd files, so I apologize if what I'm asking is vague or doesn't make sense. Obviously, I'm not well versed or practiced in using Excel and xml-schemas.

What I'm struggling with is that I have a complex, defined .xsd file from a the FDA and whenever I try to map it into Excel (2010), Excel looks busy for a minute, then *nothing*. The Source panel on Excel doesn't show the schema map and no error messages pop-up. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, if the .xsd isn't right, or something else and I definitely don't know how to address it.

Any information anyone could offer would be appreciated - Thanks!.

**Background:** For my company I'm attempting to setup an easy-to-use Excel file that will take inputs and according to a .xsd (schema?) file from the FDA, place them in an .xml file. This is for using the HL7 SPL upload process to the FDA's GUDID and the .xml format needs to be precise. .xsd file is here --> http://www.fda.gov/downloads/MedicalDevices/DeviceRegulationandGuidance/UniqueDeviceIdentification/GlobalUDIDatabaseGUDID/UCM376009.zip

Comment: Never tried anything like this before. It seems interest, so I'll see if I can figure anything out.

Comment: @xidgel Thanks! Please let me know if you figure anything out... I'm pretty stuck here

Comment: Didn't have much luck with Excel. Oddly enough, the xsd appears to open properly in MS Word.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe I could make that somehow serve my purposes. Thanks for trying!